# Generate uniform distribution under multiple constraints

Tags: python, uniform-distribution, random-generation, constraint

I have to acknowledge that my skill in statistics are really rusted.

I would like to implement in Python a uniform distribution that satisfies constraints on the mean, the median, the standard deviation, and the IQR.

Inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855569/how-to-generate-random-numbers-to-satisfy-a-specific-mean-and-median-in-python), this [post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13117-how-to-generate-a-uniform-random-variable-with-mean-zero-and-variance-ten), and this [post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-mean-and-variance-of-uniform-distribution)

If my understanding is correct, adding a constraint regarding the standard deviation to the results of the first post can be achieved this way:

```
ret = np.concatenate((arr1, mid, arr2))
mn,mx = ret.min(), ret.max()
ret = (2*ret-1) * np.sqrt(12/((mx-mn)**2)) * np.sqrt(desired_std_dev)
```

However, if someone could confirm (or correct) my guess I'd appreciate that very much.

From then on, I do not have any idea of how to apply a constraint regarding the interquantile range.

Thank for any help.

Comment: Given such statistics, there typically is no uniform distribution -- at least not on an interval.  Could you please explain, then, what you mean by "uniform"?

Comment: I really mean uniform distribution (and not normal distribution).
However I am not sure that it is possible to apply more that the mean and median as constraint on the distribution.
I do think it is possible, the goal of my question to know how.

Comment: Because any interval $(a,b)$ determines its uniform distribution, unless you carefully arrange your specifications, you will not be able to solve for $a$ and $b$ if you specify more than two constraints.

Comment: I am not sure I well understand. Let suppose the case report in the first post.
Let suppose a sequence between a and b (for any a, and any b).
It is not possible for instance to also apply a constraint regarding the standard deviation ?
Or it is possible by playing on the range (or any other parameter) between a and b ?
Or it is simply not possible ?

Comment: You might be overthinking this, because the issue is not about distributions--it's just basic algebra: each of the statistics you specify establishes a constraint on what $a$ and $b$ can be.  Once there are more than two independent constraints, there will be no solutions unless those constraints are very special.

Comment: Ok I better understand.
For my information, is the standard deviation in that context considered independent to the mean ?

Comment: The mean and SD are not independent (algebraically).  Thus, when you specify the mean and the SD of a uniform distribution on an unknown interval $(a,b),$ you determine $a$ and $b.$ In fact, provided the SD is not negative, you can *always* find a solution and it's always unique.

Comment: Ok, to resume, by determining a and b I can apply a constraint on both the mean and SD whose are not algebraically independant, but also separetely to the median for instance ?

Comment: @whuber thank you very much for your help. I really appreciated it.